# SimpleMessageConverter converts ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I create an integration message with concurrenthashmap payload as following

```
return MessageBuilder.createMessage(emvMessage.getResponse(), headers);
```

where emvMessage.getResponse() method returns

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> getResponse() {
 ...
}
```

so far so good. But when i try to receive message from api the object is becoming a HashMap

```
Object response = jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert(REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME);
```

This is because SimpleMessageConverter class converts all MapMessages to HashMap in the following method.

```
 protected Map<String, Object> extractMapFromMessage(MapMessage message) 
throws JMSException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    Enumeration en = message.getMapNames();

    while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String)en.nextElement();
        map.put(key, message.getObject(key));
    }

    return map;
}
```

Can a new feature be added or this situation can be considered as a bug? Or should i convert this hashmap to concurrenthashmap manually?

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass the simple converter and override `extractMapFromMessage()`.